# Akamai Edgescape?

Tags: akamai

I was wondering if anyone has any links to on how to implement Akamai's Edgescape solution to get the zip code?  I tried scouring the web for some sort of documentation from Akamai, but couldn't find any docs online, thought I would ask here first before contacting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Akamai account and have access to the control panel (https://control.akamai.com/), here is a document where you will find the information you need : https://control.akamai.com/dl/customers/ESCAPE/EdgeScape_users_guide.pdf

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an apples and oranges question.  If you're using a CDN, by design, a percentage of requests that would normally be directed at your web server will be offloaded by the CDN.  Of the total number of requests, those that make it through can be configured to provide the "True IP" of the client if you prefer.

As of 04/12 this is configured by adding the optional "Edge Services General" feature to your config, then enabling the "True Client IP Header".

As a bonus feature, if you're a Rails shop I'd suggest changing the name of the header to "Client-IP".  If you do so, Rails will automatically use this header to determine the real ip for the user.  This works as of 3.2.x, as documented here in [ActionDispatch:: RemoteIp](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L45)

Note: Rails appends the HTTP_ to the header :)

Comment: I realize this is two years later, but I wanted to update my response.  Last year Akamai released Luna, a new control panel.  To make akamai send you a header that includes all the geo information that they know about each request, you choose "Edit Property", then "Add Behavior", and then finally add "Content Targeting". You'll get a header that looks like:

X-Akamai-Edgescape: georegion=1,countrycode=reserved,regioncode=reserved,city=reserved,dma=reserved,pmsa=reserved,msa=reserved, areacode=reserved,county=reserved,fips=reserved,lat=reserved,long=reserved,timezone=reserved

Etc.